# How to do hourly build in CruiseControl

Tags: cruisecontrol

I need to trigger a build every 6 hours. How to do that in cruise control?
The timebuild tag just allows me to trigger the build at a particular time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for example -

**config.xml**

```
<!-- Build every 6 hours -->
<schedule interval="21600">
<composite>
...

</composite>
</schedule>
```

Or you can mix build after a particular time threshold and build on schedule -

```
...
<modificationset>
    <clearcase branch=...
     viewpath=.../>

<timebuild username=... time=.../>

</modificationset>
<schedule

interval="21600">

<ant
     antscript=...
     antWorkingDir=...
     buildfile=...
     target=.../>
</schedule>
...
```

See this article for details - http://flylib.com/books/en/2.615.1.51/1/

if you about **CruiseControl.NET**, see the *Interval Trigger* - http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/Interval%20Trigger.html

Hope this helps.